# How to load the jar files present in different location from tomcat using custom class loader

Tags: tomcat7, classloader

I would like to load the jar (developed in spring) files from my war in tomcat 7.0.5. Could you please help me out?. Detailed explanation is below.

Step 1 : A war (developed using spring) with few jars is put into the webapps folder of tomcat
Step 2 : Keep few jars (developed using spring) in different location (not inside webapps) , say /xxx/libs
Step 3 : My war should be able to load the jars from /xxx/libs and refresh the context.

Note : the jars present under /xxx/libs/ will have dependency with the jars present in the war

Please help me out.

What type of class loader should i use?
Where to place the Class loader?

Answer (score 0):

It worked By giving the location of the jars in virtual classpath to VirtualWebappLoader.

```
<Context antiJARLocking="true" path="/websandbox">
    <Loader className="org.apache.catalina.loader.VirtualWebappLoader"
            virtualClasspath="/xxx/libs/"/>
</Context>
```